# Re-assigning an array in ASP classic

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

I have the following function, designed to walk through XML and create a linear structure of all nodes:

```
function get_children(n)
  if n.hasChildNodes() then
    for each child in n.childNodes
      set local_array = array_merge(get_children(child), local_array)
    next
  else
    set local_array = Array(n)
  end if
  get_children = local_array
end function
```

I've tried a ton of variations, but I keep getting errors on the line

```
set local_array = Array(n)
```

It it's current form, I see:

```
Error Type:
Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01A8)
Object required
/_inc/nav/left-nav.inc, line 37
```

Am I mis-using the `Array()` construct?  Aren't I able to create an array with a single value?

Comment: Where do you declare (if you declare) local_array?

Comment: I'm not; but if I had given a `dim local_array` at the top of the function, I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
set local_array = Array(n)
```

to

```
local_array = Array(0)
set local_array(0) = n
```